# Statistically, which embedded system is the most used in Cryptography/Security?

Tags: embedded, encryption

I am considering to buy an embedded system development platform (electronic board + software) for Cryptography and Computer Security.

Statistically, which embedded system is the most used in Cryptography/Security in Industry and personal learning purposes?

I would use them for hardware implementation of Cryptography.

Comment: Where do you want to use it for?
Please note that there is a big difference between microcontrollers and arm/processor based boards.

Comment: The four devices you name are very different from each other, and it's difficult to think of anything you could be doing that would work equally well on all four.

Comment: I rolled this back to an earlier version that addresses cryptography, because that is what the two answers cover.  Rather than delete the aspect of the question, I new question should be asked.  If cryptography/security are removed from the question, the answers don't make any sense.

Comment: That's why I casted a delete vote, but rolling back makes sense as well @tcrosley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many manufacturers of microcontrollers --  Atmel, Freescale, Microchip, NXP, Silicon Labs, STMicroelectronics, Texas Instruments and others now include **hardware encryption/decryption engines** in some of their microcontrollers.  They are packaged a as separate module showing up as a set of registers, like I/O but without any pins, similar to a CRC-32 module might be included.  All of the ones mentioned below do AES, many do DES and 3DES as well, along with RSA, SHA etc.

- Atmel: AT91SAM family
- Freescale: Kinetis family, i.MX
- Microchip: PIC24F "GB2" family, e.g. PIC24FJ128GB204, also PIC12F635/PIC16F636/639
- NXP: A710x family (8051)
- Silicon Labs: EFM32 family
- STMicroelectronics: ST33 family, STM8L162M8, STM8L162M
- Texas Instruments: CC430 family,  AM3894/3892

This by no means an exhaustive list!  But it shows that there is support for hardware encryption/decryption not only for 32-bit processors, but 8-bit and 16-bit as well -- yes, hardware AES support for 8051s and PIC12s.  Who'd have thought.

This article, ["Secure Microcontrollers Keep Data Safe"](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/jul/secure-microcontrollers-keep-data-safe) covers many of the processors I've mentioned here, plus many some others.

I have no idea which is the most popular though. As much as I like Microchip, your best bet would probably be to pick one of the 32-bit ARM implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the security industry is using either custom hardware, special security processors, or PC-in-a-box systems. e.g. Yubikey devices http://hexview.com/~scl/neo/ use a NXP A7005.

That's "none of the above", although you could probably build some interesting things with the Spartan. I don't know about the availability of eval boards for dedicated security processors

(You can learn quite a lot of infosec and reverse-engineering tools on a regular PC, though)

Comment: Still not mentioned: Inside Secure VaultIC.